# MongoDB select multiple kind of posts types in less queries amount

Tags: mongodb, performance, processing-efficiency

For the example, in DB there are kind of posts; 
`Type A`, `Type B`, `Type C`.

I want to display each type in each section.
Maybe like this:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="x in type_a">{{x}}</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="x in type_b">{{x}}</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="x in type_c">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now I can do it just by select all posts kind and then refilter them to the targeted array. And have the data in one query.

But, If I do something like this in the find query of MongoDB: `.limit(10)`

I can receive only posts from one type and miss the other 10 posts from the other types, which are stored just after the first selected.

I can, ofcourse run a query 3 times and make it to be slow.

What is the correct way to handle such a case?

Thanks.

Comment: You may say `<ul><li ng-repeat="x in type_a">{{x}}</li></ul>` instead of `<ul>...</li>` isn't it ?

Comment: oops, yes, ive edited this :)